# Get all permutations of bool array

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

I need all permutations of a bool array, the following code is inefficient, but does what I want:

```
from itertools import permutations
import numpy as np
n1=2
n2=3

a = np.array([True]*n1+[False]*n2)

perms = set(permutations(a))
```

However it is inefficient and fails for long arrays. Is there a more efficent implementation?

Comment: `itertools.permutations()` returns a generator itself, instead of casting it into set, you can iterate through that generator and process the permuation.

Comment: @Jay sure I can, but I get a lot of dubilcates that way.

Comment: what do you mean with duplicates? you refer [True, False] is equal to [False, True]?

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte I think he means that `[True1, True2, False]` is equal to `[True2, True1, False]`

Comment: @chc I see, I m not sure but in that case using combinations from functools would not solve the issue?

Comment: `permutations(a)` is very efficient, it returns an iterator already. The fundamental problem is that the task you have described is scales something like factorial time complexity, `O(n!)` or `O(n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*1)`

Comment: to give you a sense of how this scales, for a length of 5, that's 120 permutations. For a length of 10, that is 3,628,800 permuations. For a length of 20, that is 2,432,902,008,176,640,000 permutations. Even if you could do each permutation in a nanosecond (in reality, it will take much longer) it would take 0.12 microseconds for length five, 3.62 microseconds for length ten, and a little over 70 years for length twenty.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: In case of n1=1 and n2=19 the original code uses 70 years just to find 20 possible combinations. Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about sampling the combinations of indices of the True values:

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(n1+n2)

out = [np.isin(a, x).tolist() for x in combinations(range(n1+n2), r=n1)]
```

Output:

```
[[True, True, False, False, False],
 [True, False, True, False, False],
 [True, False, False, True, False],
 [True, False, False, False, True],
 [False, True, True, False, False],
 [False, True, False, True, False],
 [False, True, False, False, True],
 [False, False, True, True, False],
 [False, False, True, False, True],
 [False, False, False, True, True]]
```